# Why do differentials have a linear relationship?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vectors

I recently learned that $$\mathrm dz = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \mathrm dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathrm dy$$

How is this result derived? If you asked me, I would have said something like $$\big(\mathrm dz\big)^2 = \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \mathrm dx\big)^2 + \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \mathrm dy \big)^2$$ (assuming that taking the square of differentials is a valid operation.)

Doesn't the equation [in its correct form] imply that the change in $z$ is linearly dependent on $x$ and $y$? Why isn't this tantamount to saying that $||\vec v|| = v_x + v_y$ for some 2D vector?

Comment: Suppose we fix all directions except one, and look at how a  slight perturbation in that direction, which we may refer to as $dx$, relates to a slight perturbation in $z$, which is a function of many variables including $x$. What the chain rule would tell you is that the ratio between these changes is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, or so to speak, the $x$ component of $dz$ should be given by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$. Then, we are doing this for all possible directions $x,y$ etc. and taking the vector sum of these.

Comment: Therefore, the linear relationship follows from the fact that yes, in each direction, we have $dz$ as a vector, and the net change is obtained by vector addition of each change.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг this is a great answer! But you should post it as an answer...

Comment: @Holo I felt it was too small, and probably lacked the insight that someone more experienced may be able to give.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I don't think so. Ofc that there are better answers, but this can be said about everything. You gave an answer that explains what he asked for, and your answer is very clear.

Comment: @Holo Thank you for your encouragement. I shall proceed in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, I do not even know what you mean by $dz$ : in truth we would like it to mean "infinitesimal change in $z$", but that's a very poor definition of something that is ubiquitous in calculus.

However, if we keep that idea in mind (let's forget the definition for once) and think about if $z=f(x,y)$, then why $dz$ must depend on $dx$ and $dy$ linearly, an answer would come as follows:

Fix all coordinates but one. Now, note that the change of $z$ *in the direction specified by* $x$ is given by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$. Therefore, a slight perturbation in the direction of $x$, given by $dx$, leads to a slight perturbation in the same direction, whose magnitude is given by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. That is, the change $dz$ in the direction of $x$, is a vector, whose direction is $dx$ and whose magnitude is given by the partial derivative.

Now, the total change must be given by the addition of these vectors. And that is why, $dz$ ends up depending linearly on each of the components $dx,dy$ etc.

If you notice, the magic here is done by the chain rule : the "loosely stated" fact that $dz= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$ is the key here.

Now, if $v = c_1v_1+c_2v_2 + ...$ then if $\{v_i\}$ are orthonormal, it is indeed true that $||v||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2$, which is the magnitude of the entire vector $dz$. It turns out that with the $dx$ and $dy$ that we have this as the case,so $||dz||^2 = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}$, which should be the expected magnitude of the change in $z$ given the changes in $x$ and $y$.

All this, however, is done *very unrigorously* : to be taken with very many helpings of salt. But in the end, you should understand that the chain rule is the magical ingredient here : it is the one that allows us to establish a linear relationship between $dz$, and $dx,dy$ etc. : one that is a mere comfort at an initial stage, and is later very essential when we get into manifolds etc. (where by the way, things like $dx,dy,dz$ are defined rigorously, and this formula continues to hold with far more rigour and application).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing it with the differential of curve length.

Given that $z$ is a scalar field $z = f(x, y)$, the expression $\dfrac{dz}{dt}$ measures the change in height along the curve $(x(t), y(t))$.
This is equivalent to the directional derivative $D_u f$ in the direction $u = (\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}).$  This leads to the definition of the chain rule: $\dfrac{dz}{dt} = D_u f = \nabla f \cdot u = \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}. $

Answer (score 1):

For f: $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ $$dz=f_xdx+f_ydy$$ is a scalar quantiy (i.e. a number), whereas the gradient $$\Delta f=(f_x,f_y)$$ is a vector.

Indeed you can think to the scalar quantity $dz$ as a dot product between $\Delta f$ and $(dx, dy)$ vectors.